# Background image scroll smoothly to certain (x,y) point

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I built a 'window' like `div` and a larger image (its a map of the world) behind it, so the user can actually "grab" it and scroll to any direction. The next goal is to let the user choose his country and the map will center around that country. Since its a custom map I need to input coordinates my self, no problem here. Right now (for demo purposes) I created a point to which the image centers. The transition is immediate, how can I scroll smoothly to that `x,y` point using jQuery `animate` property?

Right now, this is how I scroll to points:

```
var country_1 = new Position(-700,-800);
$("button").click(function(){
    country_1.Apply(document.getElementById('draggableElement'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gskot27/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`animate` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the change:

```
var anim = {};
if(!isNaN(this.X))
    anim.left = this.X;
if(!isNaN(this.Y))
    anim.top = this.Y;
$(element).animate(anim, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3gskot27/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that disables the scroll-ability of the image, it works only if the user triggers the animation first.

Comment: @undroid: Ok, then you would add that in a separate method to use for smooth scolling, and keep the original `Apply` method for the scrollability.